# Thymeleaf - Spring . Accessing a object property inside another object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-el

I have this classes

```
public class Guardian {

    public Guardian() {
        super();
    }

    private Long id;

    private String name;
..
}

public class AlarmNotification {


    private Long id;


    private Guardian guardian;
}
```

and in my Thymeleaf template

```
<td class="col_name" th:text="${alarmNotification.guardian.name}"></td>
```

But I got this Exception

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

Comment: The guardian is null in the AlarmNotification. You have to initialize the guardian to access the name property.

Comment: it is set on the controller

Comment: can you add the controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guardian is null. Add ternary operator for processing this case :

```
<td class="col_name" th:text="${alarmNotification.guardian == null ? '' : alarmNotification.guardian.name}"/>
```